# Convert subsequent SQL to case insensitive in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado, sqldatareader

We are converting from ASE (Sybase) to SQL Server (yay!)

Unfortunately, we have a ton of SQL built into our C# code which assumes ASE's default case insensitivity.

We are using ADO for both.

Is there something I can prepend in SQL to force all following queries in the batch to be case insensitive?

Is there something I can set on the ADO `SqlDataReader` to make the query run case insensitive?

Our DBA is very reluctant to change the collation on the db, the tables or the columns (ms = right, ase = wrong)

I know I can change the where clause in each to

```
WHERE 
    user_login_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS = :user_login_name
```

instead of

```
WHERE user_login_name = :user_login_name
```

and that works.

I'm hoping to not have to modify every piece of SQL, so I'd like to make a change in the library code to make it all "just work" for all our existing code.

I can modify the C# code, or inject SQL at the top and or bottom of each query easily enough, but I'm open to other ideas.

Comment: Sql server is also case insensitive by default unless you choose a case sensitive collation for your server or dwtwbase

Comment: You can change the (default) collation at the server, database, and column level. What collation do you currently have? "Our DBA is very reluctant to change the collation on the db, the tables or the columns" why? It seems that your business logic dictates storing and querying the data case-insensitively, so the storage provider needs to change to allow that.

Comment: If your DBA has (foolishly) changed the default collation to be case sensitive in MS SQL Server and (even more foolishly) is unwilling to set the collation in your specific database to the default, then you will probably need to inject `.ToUpper()` in all your string comparisons.

Comment: A column's collation is part of the table's schema. "We are storing the data with the wrong collation" is fundamentally the same problem as "we are storing numbers as `nvarchar`s." You've already found a band aid, finding a strong band aid doesn't address the underlying problem that your schema is incorrect.

Comment: However if you choose to keep your case sensitive collation then as far as i know your collate as where clause for every query is your best option

Comment: I am really sorry if your DBA set up your database with case-sensitive collation. That sounds like a nightmare. Was it intentional? Is there justification for it, or was it a mistake?

Comment: @BrianStork It doesn't sound intentional, since the question states the DBA does not want to change the collation from his perception of default, believing MS to be right and ASE to be wrong. That's a sentiment I'd agree with (relative to MS' product), but quick Google searches indicate MSSQL and ASE **both use the same default collation**, as one would expect given MSSQL started as a Sybase fork. I think someone screwed up the install and doesn't want to admit it.

Comment: Given that [SQL Server's default collation on en-US locales](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16#SQL-collations) is the case-insensitive `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` it sounds like your DBA has already configured the instance contrary to Microsoft's recommendations. Your DBA needs to justify the contrary choice, especially when it will have significant impacts on the application's existing code.

Comment: Collation is a fundamental part of datatype in column structures of the table. Changing collation on the server or the database does not affect columns that are already into tables. You have to recreate the column with the right collation and export/import data in anyway (ALTER TABLE ... ADD newColumn with right collation, then UPDATE oldcolumn to newcolums, then drop oldcolumn then rename newcolumn with old name).